# Which comes first? Set theory or first order logic?

Tags: logic, set-theory

Any theory hence set theory as well, has to be written in a concise logical manner. Hence logic should come first. On the other hand, first order logic, is a set of constants, a set of variables, etc... hence set theory should come first. What do you think?

Comment: Every theory must be written in some language, hence we first need to be able to speak of finite length strings over a finite alphabet, and how to manipulate these ...